# R Markdown PowerPoint - Couldn't find layout named "Title Slide"

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, pandoc

I am creating a PowerPoint Presentation from R markdown (`.rmd`) in RStudio.

```
---
title: "My Presentation"
author: "My name"
date: "6 4 2022"
output:
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---
```

The template is found, but an error occurs when rendering:

```
[WARNING] Powerpoint template warning: Couldn't find layout named "Title Slide" in provided reference doc. Falling back to the default included with pandoc.
[WARNING] Powerpoint template warning: Couldn't find layout named "Section Header" in provided reference doc. Falling back to the default included with pandoc.
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem - obviously - is that there are no master slides with those names in the `template.pptx`. Yet, when I edit the file and open the "edit master slides" view in PowerPoint, there is a title slide, and a slide with title and content and so on.

However, my Office 365 is not in English but in German. And, of course, Office will also use translations for the internal names of master slides.

What **looks like a solution** is going the master slides, right-click on the title slide -> rename layout -> and change `Titelfolie` to `Title Slide`. Repeat for all other layouts.

Yet, the problems will continue...

```
Could not find a 0th placeholder of type body
Fehler: pandoc document conversion failed with error 63
```

So, the **actual solution** is to go into the Office settings, [change the display language to English](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-language-office-uses-in-its-menus-and-proofing-tools-f5c54ff9-a6fa-4348-a43c-760e7ef148f8) and the create and edit a new PPTX file.

Comment: Does not work for me. Problem persists whatever the language settings.

Comment: Duid you create a new presentation after changing the language settings? I think this is necessary so that the master slide names are correct. Just opening an old one will probably not work. If you already did, you may want to check what master slide names the PowerPoint presentation is using.

Comment: My language settings are and were English.

Comment: How are the master templates named, if you right-click on the title slide -> rename?